# How to dynamically replace a column value with another value based on condition

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to dynamically change field value using a select query based on the person's previous room number.

Below are the data sample and the query I have tried. But it is throwing an error saying that there are multiple values returned by the inner query.

```
      ,A.[Room],A.[CSR],A.[MemberShip],A.[NatCode]
      ,A.[MarketCode],A.[Adult],A.[Children],A.[ArrDate]
      ,A.[DepDate],A.[ResvStatus], CASE WHEN A.[Room]>9000 THEN (SELECT MIN(A.[Room])FROM [RESDETAILS] C WHERE C.GuestName=A.GuestName) ELSE A.[Room] END AS [Room]
  FROM [ITHAAFUSHI].[dbo].[RESDETAILS] A
  WHERE [GuestName]= 'Mr Jobin Joseph' 
   GROUP BY 
       A.[BusinessDate],A.[GuestName],A.[TravelAgent]
      ,A.[Room],A.[CSR],A.[MemberShip],A.[NatCode]
      ,A.[MarketCode],A.[Adult],A.[Children],A.[ArrDate]
      ,A.[DepDate],A.[ResvStatus]
```

> "Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, < =,>, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression."

[image: Raw data]

Below is the expected result when Room No is >9000

[image: Expected result]

Comment: Instead of the inner query, did you tried using a left join?

Comment: That query looks incomplete.

Comment: This could be the most confusing thing I've ever had to think of in sql: case value is subquery using an aggregation function of a table *outside* the one it is referencing!! What does this mean?

Comment: Why is there a `Group By` on this query? If we saw the whole query, maybe we'd understand it.

Comment: You will struggle to overcome flawed data - especially at the query level. Your last row has different "identifying" values - e.g., ResvID (which you left out of your code snippet), ArrDate, and DeptDate. This looks like a [gaps and islands problem](https://www.itprotoday.com/sql-server/solving-gaps-and-islands-enhanced-window-functions) with a complicating purity problem. Fixing your data will solve this problem forever.

Answer (score 1):

Your `(SELECT MIN(A.[Room])FROM [RESDETAILS] C WHERE C.GuestName=A.GuestName)` 
return more than 1 row so you need to use group by inside :

`SELECT MIN(A.[Room])FROM [RESDETAILS] C WHERE C.GuestName=A.GuestName GROUP BY C.GuestName)`

Comment: How could a MIN return more than 1 value when there is no group by? Your solution would actually make this worse, not better.